Cannot install windows alongside linux on NTFS partition - unrecognised type
I am attempting to install Windows 10 Pro from a usb onto a partition that I have formatted to ntfs using
sudo mkfs.ntfs -Q /dev/sda3

When I run
df -T, --print-type 

The output includes:
/dev/sda3      fuseblk   102G   68M  102G   1% /...

But when I try to install Windows it errors

Windows  cannot be installed on this hard disk space. The partition is of an unrecognised type

What could be wong?

You assign a type to a partition even before creating a filesystem there. Maybe the Windows installer refuses to work with a partition of the "wrong" type (compare this answer). What is the output of sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda?

Also I suspect the Windows installer may try to use (create) more than one partition. It may be better to give it unallocated space and let it create partition(s) and filesystem(s) there.

@KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the pointer - I deleted the partition and recreated it as an NTFS type - now it's loading!

note: don't use the fuse ntfs-3g driver, the kernel ntfs3 driver is much much better

From the Windows installer screen where you select the partition:
Delete the partition.
Then tell Windows to use the free space as target for the installation.
Windows will re-create the partition, with the proper partition type.
Linux/fuse deals differently with partition types. It is now set to the generic "fuseblk" which is fine for Linux, but Windows really insists on type "ntfs".
And in some cases Windows wants to make 2 or 3 partitions (EFI and/or recovery), so it is best to let Windows handle its own stuff.

I am accepting this answer, but as you will see from my comment to @KamilMaciorowski I had already recreated the partition satisfactorily in linux

@Psionman It may have worked but what you should ALWAYS do is exactly what this answer says. You may force the Windows installation to a single partition (+ ESP for UEFI systems, of course) but that's subpar. Windows expects to have a recovery partition as well. If you just leave unallocated space and an accessible ESP that will be enough and RECOMMENDED for a Windows installation in your scenario.
